# Grunt - get filename by glob and use it as variable later

Tags: javascript, xslt, gruntjs

I just install grunt today, so far it is working and I really like it. I am using XSLT on my site, and I need to insert generated css/js with hash filename there.

I want to use https://github.com/tnory56/grunt-xslt but, I don't know the generated filenames - they are not static. How I can get the filename by selector and use it later in config.

Thanks for any hint, please ignore injector, I can not use it in XSLT

My config as follows:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        clean: [
                    'libs/js/combined/combined.min.v-*.js', 
                    'combined.min.v-*.css'      
                ],
        concat: {
            css: {
                src: [
                    'style.css'
                ],
                dest: 'combined.css'
            },
            js: {
                src: [
                    'libs/js/common.js'
                ],
                dest: 'libs/js/temp/combined.js'
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            css: {
                src: 'combined.css',
                dest: 'combined.min.css'
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            js: {
                files: {
                    'libs/js/temp/combined.min.js': ['libs/js/temp/combined.js']
                }
            }
        },  
      hashify: {
        simple: {
          options: {
            basedir: '', 
            copy: true, 
            hashmap: 'hashify-hashmap.json' 
          },
          files: [{
            src: 'combined.min.css', 
            dest: 'combined.min.v-{{hash}}.css', 
          },
          {
            src: 'libs/js/temp/combined.min.js',
            dest: 'libs/js/combined/combined.min.v-{{hash}}.js'
          }]    
        }
      },
      injector: {   

        options: {
            template : 'libs/xsl/main_domain/xhtml.xsl',
            destFile : 'libs/xsl/main_domain/xhtml-generated.xsl' 
        },      
        local_dependencies: {
          files: {              
            'libs/xsl/main_domain/xhtml.xsl': ['libs/js/combined/combined.min.v-*.js', 'combined.min.v-*.css'],
          }
        }

      },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-hashify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-injector');   
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'concat:css', 'cssmin:css', 'concat:js', 'uglify:js', 'hashify:simple', 'injector']);
};
```

Update: it seems grunt-xslt is not working even with their example, so I need another solution (template system compatible with XML)

Next what I tried (not XML compatible, but I think there can be workaround for this) is grunt-template, but as I though {{hash}} is not evaluated.

```
'template': {
    'process-html-template': {
        'options': {
            'data': {
                'js_file': 'libs/js/combined/combined.min.v-{{hash}}.js',
            }
        },
        'files': {
            'tmp/xhtml.xsl': ['libs/xsl/main_domain/xhtml.xsl']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for grunt template interpolation is actually `<%= ... %>` (http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template), and beware: it works on config variables, not any javascript variable

So you should use:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // ...
    'hash' : '(...your way of computing the hash...)',
    'template': {
        'process-html-template': {
            'options': {
                'data': {
                    'js_file': 'libs/js/combined/combined.min.v-<%= hash %>.js',
                }
            },
            'files': {
                'tmp/xhtml.xsl': ['libs/xsl/main_domain/xhtml.xsl']
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
});
```